# "mobile", "full site" links fail intermittently on mobile Safari

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, mobile-safari, full-site

It usually takes 2-5 tries in order to switch between mobile and full site on mobile Safari. Sometimes the page would reload without a switch to the other site. I use an iPhone 5 running on iOS 6.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You may have to ask a flight attendant for help on this one, it's clearly an aircraft problem.

Comment: @Jack It's 10 hours till the end of flight. No. I turn on airplane mode just to avoid receiving calls.

Comment: Not able to reproduce, iPhone 4S with iOS 6.1.1 are you sure you click the correct link? In the "full site" mode, the "mobile" link is very small and easy to miss when trying to click, e.g. clicking "contact us" instead.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I am sure I click the right link. After clicking the "full site" link on mobile site, the page reloads with a query string that looks like `?__=1608284802` but it doesn't switch to the full site. Just reproduced it right now.

Comment: I'm unable to repro this as well, on an iPhone, iPad, Nexus 4, 7 or any full desktop browser.  Are you behind a proxy perhaps?

Comment: @NickCraver I don't think so. I try this on my iPhone and it only occurs on Stack Overflow (not the meta site). Maybe it has something to do with caching?

Comment: @NickCraver This issue seems to be gone now. It now works fine on my iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the update, tagging appropriately :)

Comment: @NickCraver: FWIW, I get this as well occasionally on my iPhone 4S running 6.1.1. I haven't found a way to reproduce, but every once in a while, this problem will occur with exactly the same symptoms as Anthony describes (complete with random query string in the URL).